# How can I find out which process is using a file on a remote samba share?

Tags: linux, samba, files

We have a large number of processes that are business specific that have been piling up over the years on a particular server. The developers of these processes have not left much documentation and therefore we have to track down which processes are using what files.

My question is, how can I identify which process on a particular server is reaching out to a remote server share and locking a file on another system?

Here's what I know:
I know the server that's connecting
I know the file name it's locking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably mounted the Samba share. So it should not matter that the files are remote. fuser / lsof should do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we were able to trace it down using a script that ultimately uses this command.